# How can I discover the author of a blendfile?

Tags: blend-files

I know how to set the "Author" attribute for the blendfiles that I create, using `Blender User Preferences > File`.  However, I have not found out how to *view* the author of a blendfile.  How can I do this?

Comment: I don't usually like to provide alternatives, but seeing as this feature is largely useless to the average user (and cannot provide much info), I would suggest using a Text block for author info and packing it with the Blender file.

Comment: @rolandixor Whenever they are useful, alternatives are great and broaden the horizon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't, This author field is only ever used in exporters. In the COLLADA export to be precise, where the COLLADA format can have an author tag, and I wanted it to be possible for users to have a configurable content for this, so I added the author field to user preferences.

Not everybody will have this set, either, so best not to rely on this for 'correct' user data.

Answer (score 0):

You can query this in the Python Console or in a script using:

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.system.author
```